# querystring in ionic v1 using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

How do I set a querystring?

**sample:**

```
$location.path('/voucher-view?token=' + token);
```

and how do I retrieve the value?

**sample:**

```
var url = $location.search();
        var token = url.token;
```

**sample route:**

```
.state('voucher-view', {
        url: '/voucher-view',
        templateUrl: "templates/voucher-view.html",
        controller: 'VoucherViewController'
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using Angular UI router. So, to set/get query parameter in the route, you can change your state's configuration like this:

```
.state('voucher-view', {
  url: '/voucher-view?token',
  templateUrl: "templates/voucher-view.html",
  controller: 'VoucherViewController'
})
```

Note that I appended the parameter in the URL of the state. Now, when you need to pass the parameter's value, you can simply pass it in the `$state.go` call:

```
$state.go('voucher-view', { token: 'your_token_here' });
```

To retrieve it, you can use `$transition$` service to get the value. Inject it in the controller, and use it like this:

```
$transition$.params().token
```

If you're using UI Router's 0.x versions, `$transition$` will not be available. You need to use `$stateParams` for it then:

```
$stateParams.token
```